# r alternative for "rimage" - display graphics in plot

Tags: r, graphics, plot

i am searching for an alternative for "rimage" as rimage was unfortunately removed from the Cran repository. 
I want to display several small images("png") in a plot.

thanks beforehand for any good suggestions.

Curlew.

Comment: I'd take a look at the `gridExtra` package.  It lets you layout a page  with text, plots and graphics however you want.  A clearer description of what you're looking for might get some additional ideas though.

Comment: Basically i want to play around a little bit with graphics and links between them as shown in this answer -> (http://tinyurl.com/casx5rs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `rasterImage` function to plot a single image (after imported and converted to a raster) in the current plot.

You can use the `ms.image` and `my.symbols` functions in the `TeachingDemos` package to use the png as a plotting symbol in a scatterplot (see the example for `ms.image` for reading from the .png file and plotting).

Comment: Sry, made a mistake.
As i pointed out in one of the comments i wanted to recreate some graphs as displayed here(tinyurl.com/casx5rs). 
Rimage was a dependency and i thought that loading images in graphs needs additional packages. Strangely you can do all the stuff with just the png package.

    require(png)
    img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
    i <- imagematrix(img)
    plot(i)